# getting updated values from the parent activity

Tags: java, android

i am working on a project where i have to test some wifi rssi values that i am calculating in parent activity.... but for testing i have created a new activity which is launched by pressing of a button..what i want is to get the 5-6 different values from the wifi scan results and use them in test activity instead of one??

i have tried getting values in 5 different arrays and passing them to test activity but there were some complications with this method in my code.

can anybody give me some suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: what complications are you talking about ? You can use sharedPreferences as well if needed for this .

Comment: can you tell me a little more about sharedPreferences?? i have never used them

Comment: You should look at sharedPrefrences api. It is basically like a variable with application level scope, usually used to store applications settings. You can store anything and fetch from it anywhere in your application where it is available.

Comment: OK Thanks man!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Hashmap and SharedPreferences.

1 - Set your values

```
    Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
    values.put("key0", "value0");
    values.put("key1", "value1");
    values.put("key2", "value2");

    SharedPreferences keyValues = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor keyValuesEditor = keyValues.edit();

    for (String s : values.keySet()) {
        keyValuesEditor.putString(s, values.get(s));
    }

    keyValuesEditor.apply();
```

2 - Retrieve a value

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String myValue = prefs.getString("key0", null);
```

Comment: ok but in this once i start my activity i cannot get the updated value from the parent activity..right?? like when i added string "hello" in the bundle and started my activity is there any way that if after starting the child activity if the value of that string changes to "hi" can i get it in the child activity without restarting it?

Comment: Sorry, I read your question too much fast... then as others told you, you better use SharedPreferences just updated my answer.